# Требуется пояснение того, КАК функция возвращает то, что она возвращает

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

Название темы неинформативное, но по-другому описать проблему не додумался.

Как данная функция возвращает то, что она возвращает?

А именно, она возвращает список из произведений цифр числа до момента, пока это число не стало цифрой.

```
def per(n, s=0):
  return ([n] if s else []) + (per(eval('*'.join(str(n))), 1) if n > 9 else [])
```

Особенно интересует `eval`. Я нашёл много страшных и длинных статей на тему принципа работы этой функции, но хотелось бы понять для начала хотя бы азы её работы. Как она вообще работает в данном конкретном случае?

Comment: Не забивайте себе голову изучением этого очень некачественного кода, а то еще решите, что так и принято писать программы на python (спойлер: нет).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функция `eval(command)` просто выполняет Python команду `"command"` как если бы вы задали ее в интерпретаторе Python:

```
In [85]: eval("print(1, 2)")
1 2

In [86]: eval("3 * 4")
Out[86]: 12
```

---

В приведенной вами функции число превращается в строку цифр, разделенную знаком умножения между каждой цифрой: `234` --> `"2*3*4"`. После этого функция `eval(...)` считает произведение всех цифр.

Но, во-первых, этого можно достичь проще - просто дописать `"1"` в начале или в конце числа и перемножить все цифры. Таким образом нам не придется беспокоиться о числах, состоящих из одной цифры:

```
def prod(n):
    return eval('*'.join('1' + str(n)))
```

А, во-вторых, как вы уже сами заметили, использование функции `eval(...)` может представлять серьезные проблемы безопасности, поэтому лучше сначала всегда попробовать обойтись без этой функции.

```
def prod(n):
    res = 1
    while n > 0:
        n, mod = divmod(n, 10)
        res *= mod
    return res
```